# How to refresh html element after modifying element

Tags: html, angular

I have been trying to print after modifying html element but element has not been changed. (Angular2)
This source code is simplified one.

```
<div *ngIf="displayType === 'screen'">
       <div>This is Screen</div>  
</div>
<div *ngIf="displayType === 'print'">
       <div>This is Print</div>  
</div>
```

And when click a button the following event.

```
    displayType: string = 'screen'; // default
    OnPrint() { 
           this.displayType = 'print'; 
           let tmp = document.createElement('div');
           let el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);   

           tmp.appendChild(el); 

           let content = tmp.innerHTML;
           let frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
           document.body.appendChild(frame1); 
           let frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow;    
           frameDoc.document.open();
           frameDoc.document.write('<html><body>'+content+'</body></html>');
           frameDoc.document.close();

           setTimeout(function () {
               window.frames["frame1"].focus();
               window.frames["frame1"].print();
               document.body.removeChild(frame1);
           }, 500); 
  }
```

But contents are elements before modifying.
How can I refresh elements?

Comment: What's the purpose of this. I can't make any sense of this code. Angular2 doesn't care about HTML you add dynamically. What exactly should update?

Comment: I need to change layout when printing. That's why I need to modify html. I mentioned Angular2 in case people don't know Angular2

Answer (score 1):

To refresh the elements you need to trigger the change detection.
Here is a very good post about change detection in Angular 2: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

I've created a plunker here to illustrate it:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZwkaQ776mKpLYZJogYx?p=preview

```
<button (click)="OnPrint()">OnPrint</button>
```

Also you should not modify the DOM elements directly, you should create a component and use a structural directive to display it (here the component has a selector "my-print"):

```
<my-print *ngIf="isPrint" [iframeSrc]="..."></my-print>
```